# Screen doesn't change after pressing a button in Xcode simulator

Tags: xcode, kivy

My Kivy app work fine in python2. Running in Xcode (10.1) simulator gives me the main screen, but pressing button does not bring me to the second one (drawing screen). Interestingly when moving and pressing on the mouse, the app print the coordinates as it should.
I've tried create a very simple project with only 1 button and 2 screens: again, on python works OK but in the simulator not.

Any suggestions?

python

```
class MainScreen(Screen):  

    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    test_type = ObjectProperty(None)
    test_date = ObjectProperty(None)

    def reset(self):
        self.username.text = ""
        self.test_type.text = ""
        self.test_date.text = ""

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass     
class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class DrawInput(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):

        timing_ms = ApplePenApp.get_running_app().sw_seconds
        print('test')

        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0)
            touch.ud["line"] = Line(points = (touch.x, touch.y))    

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        timing_ms = ApplePenApp.get_running_app().sw_seconds
        touch.ud["line"].points += (touch.x, touch.y)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):     
        timing_ms = ApplePenApp.get_running_app().sw_seconds

presentation = Builder.load_file("applepen_kivy.kv")

class ApplePenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

if __name__=="__main__":
    ApplePenApp().run()
```

Kivy

```
# File name: main.py
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
        id: main
    SecondScreen:

    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    #define global variables 
    username: username
    test_type: test_type
    test_date: test_date

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        #organise the window
        size: root.width, root.height

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2

            Label: 
                text: "Username: "
                color: 0.5,0.5, 0.5, 1
                font_size: 30
            TextInput:
                id: username
                multiline: False
                font_size: 30
            Label: 
                text: "Copy/Recall/Recall2: "
                color: 0.5,0.5, 0.5, 1
                font_size: 30
            TextInput:
                id: test_type
                multiline: False
                font_size: 30
            Label: 
                text: "Date: "
                color: 0.5,0.5, 0.5, 1
                font_size: 30
            TextInput:
                id: test_date
                multiline: False
                font_size: 30

        Button:
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: app.root.current = "drawing" 


<SecondScreen>:
    name: "drawing"

    FloatLayout:

        DrawInput:
            id: drawing

        Button:
            font_size: 30
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.05
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.4, "bottom": 1}
            text: "finish"
            on_release: app.root.current = "main"
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem.

Comment: I've edited the comment.